# How to save a file using officejs when not in Outlook Web?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

I have an Outlook add-in that identifies if the email being read has any attachments, and prompts the user to action against them if they wanted. The action manipulates the file, and then wants to save it... somewhere for the user to be able to now view.

In Outlook Web (https://outlook.office.com) I am able to trigger a browser download (chrome, ff, and safari), but this is not an option in Outlook for Mac. (I assume the same for windows.)

I don't know how to create and save a file when in Outlook for Mac or Windows clients.

I also do not have the ability to addfileAttachmentFromBase64Async()  when in read command surface. If that were present, I could attach the manipulated file... to then be viewable by clicking on it.

Is this possible? Has anyone figured any creative workaround to saving a file on a desktop client from an outlook add-in?

Edit: Thanks to the assistance of @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT in the comments below so far I have been able to utilize window.open() from my add-in in this way.

```
openNewWindow(): void {
  const wnd = window.open('data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + base64Image);
  setTimeout(function() {
    wnd.close();
  }, 3000);
}
```

Again, though, this will download/save a file when in OWA, but does not in Outlook for Mac/Windows. It will open the window, but no file will save/download.

I suspect there may be potential combination answer here with window.open() and one of these solutions? [How to save a file in Outlook from Add-in [taskpane or otherwise]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66358499/how-to-save-a-file-in-outlook-from-add-in-taskpane-or-otherwise)

A big issue with this Desktop client limitation [other than it's not working the way I require to deliver my add-on], is that I have also not found a way [in the manifest for the add-in or otherwise] to limit my Add-in from being available on the Desktop Clients [where it would not currently work].

Comment: addfileAttachmentFromBase64Async is a compose mode API because user cannot add attachment in read mode. What's your approach with OWA (Outlook web) to trigger browser download? What's the issue you see with the same approach with Mac/Windows? Would opening a browser work for the scenario?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, yea it generally makes sense to me why addfileAttachmentFromBase64Async would only be available on compose mode. I use javascript to trigger a file download in OWA.
```
   const a = document.createElement("a");
   a.target = "_blank";
   a.href = "data:image/png;base64," + base64File;
   a.download = newfilename;
   a.click();
```

Comment: I was under the impression that the taskpane runs as an embedded safari window, yes?  (outside of scope for this quextion) Another issue i'm having is that the Safari Web Inspector closes if the taskpane closes, so i can't inspect any console during taskpane initialization either.

I had not tried my add-in in OWA on safari yet... I'll do that now.

Comment: I have confirmed the add-in works in OWA in Safari.

Comment: got it. I am not familiar with the data uri usage and its limitation. One alternative is to try opening default browser window for the download (openBrowswerWindow in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui?view=outlook-js-preview) Commenting on the other parts - yes addins run in embedded web engine based on OS/environment: info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins

Comment: For debugging, see options here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/test-debug-office-add-ins and you may consider putting your download code to trigger after a button click to give you a chance to attach after initialization.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, I was unable to use Office.context.ui.openBrowswerWindow. I only have closeContainer(), and displayDialogAsync() on that [read] command surface. I don't see it anywhere in OfficeJS.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, I was even unsuccessful trying to use displayDialogAsync() and then trying to initiate a file download in JavaScript from the dialog.html and dialog.js.  Any ideas on how to access openBrowserWindow()?  or any other ideas on any Office API calls I can use to safe a file to the user's desktop?

Comment: I suggest looking a bit deeper into openBrowserWindow to do this. For openBrowserWindow being unavailable, could you tell us the Outlook build version and platform you are testing with? There are older versions of Outlook that openBrowswerWindow may not be available and window.open could be an alternative.

Comment: Thank you for your response! In this particular test, I'm using Catalina OSX 10.15.7. And the client is Microsoft Outlook for Mac v16.46. I made an edit to my post above with some relevant information about window.open(). Please advise. :)

Comment: openBrowserWindow is indeed what we want here. Support for it in Win32 should be implemented on most recent C2R builds in the last 2 years. I am not sure what the status of it is on Mac and will have to follow up with that team to find out what builds they are in.

Comment: So openBrowserWindow will allow me to save a file from said window?  Do you happen to have any sample/demo code anywhere?

Comment: Open Browser window allows you to open a URL in the default browser. From there you could do anything a normal browser window could do. (which could include downloading a file). I don't have sample code for file downloading, but sample code for OpenBrowser window is in the above links)

Comment: Could you please try this sample code in Mac Outlook and let us know the result. `Office.context.ui.openBrowserWindow("https://office.com");`
If this does not work for you, let us know Office js version being used by the Add-in?

Comment: Yea, I have mentioned all of this above. The result of that code will not compile. `Property 'openBrowserWindow' does not exist on type 'UI'.ts(2339)`. There are only two methods closeContainer(), and displayDialogAsync() on Office.context.ui. 

Could there be something specific required in the manifest to open certain OfficeJS APIs?

I have tried on several OS, and a few Outlook client versions.

Comment: I did try removing Typescript from the equation by `let nonTypeScriptUI: any = Office.context.ui;
    nonTypeScriptUI.openBrowserWindow("https://office.com");`

but still received `AppComponent.html:17 ERROR TypeError: nonTypeScriptUI.openBrowserWindow is not a function`

Also it does not matter if I am reading a message nor composing one.

Comment: I'm not sure why your TS isn't compiling. However, if you install ScirptLab (from the Office Store) you can run this gist https://gist.github.com/exextoc/152d7512cd855c62151d5989f3aea276

That should show how this function is supposed to work.

Comment: Here is a scriptlab gist - https://gist.github.com/hiddenkirby/d75d4ea1c34c9230d0faa028eb3a9c07

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, So openBrowserWindow() is not compatible with Web clients. (I will need a way to determine which method to use based on client type.).  I am still unable to download a file with openBrowserWindow(). (See above gist.)